# Django static files in live server using nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I have a live server running django, the address is http://179.188.3.54/ . As you can see, the app works but looks like the static files arent working. Also if I click in any other link, doesnt work.

This website is running without any problems in development version. Im not sure what I should do to fix this problem.

Here is my nginx config file and my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/cinegloria/cinegloria/cinegloria/static/'
```

PS: I tried to run collectstatic ;)

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.html index.htm;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000/;
}
}
```

Any ideas or sample code will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the static serving to the nginx conf before the `/` pattern:

```
location /static {
    alias /cinegloria/cinegloria/cinegloria/static/;
}

location / {
    ...
}
```

Or set the `STATIC_ROOT` to the directory under the www root:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/usr/share/nginx/www/static'
```

Or add the symlink from www root to you static dir:

```
$ ln -s /cinegloria/cinegloria/cinegloria/static /usr/share/nginx/www/static
```

Comment: Good one! It's working now. Your code is missing a ; in the end of alias line. Anyway, thanks for your answer. And about my pages, if I click in any link, is not working, it can be also nginx problem?

Comment: For example contact page, http://179.188.3.54/contato/ ... any other page that I click, I get this error... [22/Feb/2015:23:50:37 -0300] "GET /contato/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1308 "http://179.188.3.54/"

Comment: Try to comment the `try_files` directive.  You don't need it for the regular django app.

Answer (score 1):

Add another nginx directive for the static files. Static files should be served by nginx, not the Django server.

```
location  /static/ {
    alias  /cinegloria/cinegloria/cinegloria/static/;
}
```

If that still doesn't work, you may need to add the mime type directive. I had to do that yesterday, because for some reason nginx wasn't serving the correct mime type when I used an alias.

As a helpful pointer, whenever you run into problems like this, take a look at your nginx error log and paste the last few lines for debugging. It is located at /var/log/nginx/error.log or a similar path.

Comment: Do you know why my pages are broken? Seems like the links are not working. Is that a nginx problem ? do you know?